# ExtJS4 Selector in a Region

Tags: extjs4, css-selectors

I am attempting to ref a grid that is in a region:

```
...
region: 'south',
layout: 'fit',
split: true,
items:[{
     xtype: 'grid',
     border: false
     ...
}]
...
```

in the refs section of my controller but I do not know how to reference the actual grid inside the region:

```
{ref: 'myGrid',selector:'????'}
```

Will someone please kick me in the right direction, please.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

refs are intended for views, not for components. The reason for that is that only one controller can ref a specific view. What you use as a selector is one of the alias for the view. So you'll have to create a view that extends Ext.panel.Panel and contains an Ext.grid.Panel or a view that extends Ext.grid.Panel. This view must have an alias on its own and that alias is what you use as your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ref, I added an itemId to the grid component and can access it in the controller using Ext.ComponentQuery().